# How do I troubleshoot poor Wifi speed

Tags: wireless-networking, macbook-pro

This may not be a macbook issue as much as a networking issue.

When I connect my macbook through thunderbolt lan connection, use the speed test (speedtest.net) I get upload of 26.5mbps.  When I connect through wifi I get 3.5mbps.

How do I go about troubleshooting this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First 3 steps:

1. Connect with your phone to the WiFi network and test using speedtest app the connection (use the same server)
2. Check the wifi properties and look at PHY Mode (should be G / N) http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/38628/how-to-see-your-current-wi-fi-connection-speed-in-mac-os-x/
3. Use your wifi scanner, and see if there is interference with other wifi connections in your area. (http://letstalk-tech.com/access-wifi-scanner-mac-os-x-mavericks/)